# count(*) in mysql innodb table leading to inconsistent results while data is pumped via spring xd

Tags: mysql, spring, unix, spring-xd

```
       echo -e "job create --name $completeJobName --definition \"filejdbc --resources=file:/var/lib/wwhs/eligibility/processing/complete/* 
--names=file_id,client_id,member_record_number,membe    r_first_name,member_middle_initial,member_last_name
,group_id,member_id,date_of_birth,created_by,created_date,modified_by
,modified_date 
--tableName=eligibility.eligibility_file_staging_complete\" --deploy" > $completeJobCmdFile

           /var/lib/spring_xd/shell/bin/xd-shell script $completeJobCmdFile                        # Call XD to create the complete job
             /var/lib/spring_xd/shell/bin/xd-shell job launch $completeJobName                       # Run XD processing for simple input files
             rm $completeJobCmdFile
```

In the above code, we are pushing the data via spring XD from a .csv file to a MySQL table. We are then reading the count(*) from the table. Once the count matches the count in the file header, we are initiating the next SQL to process rows from this staging table.

The problem I am facing is that the count(*) is varying. So, when i match it in the if-else condition with header value, it matches.

Later, the count is much lower. The table-type is InnoDB, can that be the issue ?

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not sure what would cause the `count(*)` query to be varying in it's results, since you're using a job to import the data, why not launch the next process once the job is complete?  In Spring XD, job related events can be listened to so that you can execute dependent processes.

You can read more about the job related notifications here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#_retrieve_job_notifications

Comment: Thanks Michael for sharing this link. I will try changing my script to listen to the completion and then execute. Will keep you posted.

Comment: Thanks Michael for guiding me in the right direction. I am able to control the flow using the XD listener.